# Passing Return Key via Shell Script

Tags: ssh, php, shell-script, nohup

I'm using `phpseclib` to run a shell script on my server at a given interval. That script involves using `nohup`. For whatever reason, if there isn't a user ready to send SIGINT or a return to `nohup` once it's launched, it kills the process.

For instance, if I run the script via a local prompt it runs, then all I have to do is hit enter and I get a new cmd prompt. When I try and run it automatedly, I can't pass the return or a SIGINT and the process never finishes. Ideas?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `nohup` with GNU `screen`? What function does `nohup` provide that can't be provided by `screen`?

Comment: @allquixotic Screen requires an active terminal, and therefore cannot be run solely over an ssh command.

Comment: Are you already aware of the information in [this](http://askubuntu.com/questions/115819/sorry-could-not-find-a-pty) AU post?

Answer (score 0):

Normally I've used an ugly TCL/Tk framework called Expect to do this sort of thing in the past. I noticed there is a php version of expect called [PHP:Expect](http://www.php.net/manual/en/expect.examples-usage.php). Perhaps that will help here?

Expect should allow you to simulate a console connection and send any key squence. Be warned though these frameworks can be painful. If you aren't tied to PHP take a look at [Ashier](https://code.google.com/p/ashier/) which sounds awesome (although I've never used it).